# Default page for a host name in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a website with 4 binding in IIS 7.5

I want if user use {Host Name 1} then default document be {Default1.aspx}

I want if user use {Host Name 2} then default document be {page/Default1.aspx}

I want if user use {Host Name 3} then default document be {page/admin/Default3.aspx}

How do I implement ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 different ways that you can use.

- [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Server Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [RewritePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kz7fdx9(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Let IIS handle it, and create there a new host with virtual directory to your path.

Each one have their positives and negatives. You capture on `global.asax` the BeginRequest, and there you implement your logic, **for example using RewritePath**, an example that you need to test and evolve.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string sTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sTheFile);

    if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if(Request.Url.Host == "www.hostname2.com")
        {           
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/page/default1.aspx", false);          
        }
        else if(Request.Url.Host == "www.hostname3.com")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/page/admin/Default3.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            // for default1.aspx - leave it as is       
        }       
    }
}
```

And one article on msdn [Redirect Users to Another Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @HoseinEghbal Is not that simple as is looks, this can work for one page the default, but you need also to check and for the actual file (if is the default or some other). You have some more work to do with it... start with this and you see the rest that you need to fix on the progress.